# Asp.Net MVC Bundle append text to Urls

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bundle

I have a bundle like this:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js",
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js",
                      "~/Scripts/alertify.js"));
```

I was to append my application version as a query string to the generated urls, like this "//app/scripts/bootstrap.js?1-0-4-9".  This is to work around browser caching.

I tried: `"~/Scripts/bootstrap.js" + version`, but that did not work.  The file never got added to the Html.  Any suggestions?

**Update** This is an internal web app that I cannot build in release mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bundles you do not need to add the version it already adds a special key if you run the application in the release mode.

Comment: I cannot run my app in release mode, it has to be debug. What if I BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true; in Global.asax?  Would that give the behavior I desire?

Comment: Yes, BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true worked in debug! Thanks for pointing me the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The Bundle system will automatically handle browser cache issues for you when the included .js files change.

> If any file in the bundle changes, the ASP.NET optimization framework will generate a new token, guaranteeing that browser requests for the bundle will get the latest bundle.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification